# Запятая перед союзом "и" после придаточного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, и, придаточное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед союзом "и"?

"Если стиральная машина не включилась, проверьте, что вилка вставлена **в розетку, и попробуйте** ещё раз".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

При изъятии придаточного остаётся главное предложение, в котором однородные сказуемые связаны союзом «и»: ***проверьте и попробуйте ещё раз***.

> Запятая ставится между главным и придаточным предложениями, а если придаточное стоит внутри главного, то оно выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон ([Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/146-zap-19-26)).